# Android Studio emulator appears in the task manager for 10 seconds and disappears. The emulator window is never displayed

Tags: android, android-studio

It was working fine till I updated the Android SDK tools from the SDK Manager to version 24.1.2. However a virtual device was running at the time of the update and it asked me to close 3 processes in order for the update to continue. I thought the virtual device was interfering  so I closed it and tried to proceed with the update,it gave me the same error. Therefore I cancelled the update and closed the studio. After restarting the studio,it gave an error saying the SDK could not be found and would not let me do anything else. I uninstalled the studio after deleting the SDK folder and reinstalled it. I downloaded the system images needed for the virtual devices and some other packages and created a new virtual device. When I tried to run the application,it gave me the dialogue box to chose the virtual device,I chose the newly created one and it gave the command to start the device. Yet no emulator window for the device appeared.

`D:\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd MTK
emulator: device fd:5500
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode`

HAXM is installed and it worked fine before. On checking the task manager upon launching the application,an emulator-x86.exe process appears briefly before disappearing. Nothing happens after that. Launching the program again gives the same result. If I try to launch the device from the AVD manager,I get the same result. I have tried using the arm images,varying the ram size,snapshot enabled/disabled,use HOST GPU enabled/disabled,system restarted,removal of /.android content,setting up the SDK in a different drive and deleting the  ANDROID_SDK_HOME system variable and resetting it.

I have also tried with Genymotion. The virtual device window briefly appears and I can the see the android logo at startup but then it says "player.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience." I have tried it using both the Genymotion Android SDK tools and the custom Android SDK tools to no avail. If I try to delete the device it says please stop the virtual device before deleting it even though it is not running.

Answer (score 0):

I spent most of my day trying to solve exactly the same problem until one of my colleagues remembered he had exactly the same issue and that was related to Docker.

Docker uses Hypervisor Framework which is incompatible with the HAXM used by the Android emulator. Therefore if you try to run the Android emulator while Docker is running it will just quit without a warning. Quitting Docker will allow to use the simulator - [Docker for Mac conflict with Android emulator](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24530)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is because you are low on memory, or it might be an AVD specific glitch.  I had many (20) devices saved in my AVD and was lower than normal on memory on my laptop.  The native emulator folder would disappear right away but genymotion worked fine.

I removed the old devices and create a new one from scratch in AVD and the problem disappeared.